# How to make the menu pointing to specific page sections

Tags: google-sites

I am currently trying to implement a single page on Google Sites but I can't figure out how to make the menu pointing to specific page sections. I do think it's possible since there's already a working example online.

Ideally I want to make a section eg, Gallery and anchor that onto #gallery via a custom link. Anyone has an idea how I can go about implementing jump links on Google Sites?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. You are using the new Google Sites app instead of the Classic one, right?

Comment: @Rubén Yes exactly, did they change things in the new version? Basically I just want to use anchored links, but in this case many items should be linking to whatever headings are available on the site.

Comment: @Rubén something along the lines of this site: https://vip-nailsbeauty.business.site/#testimonials

Comment: [Possible duplicate(https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/153812/88163) (no answers at this time)